# How to run a baker with ledger (remote signer)

Tags: remote-signer

I would like to know how to run a node on a VPS using hardware wallet. Everyone is recommending me to dig on "remote signer" but I coudln't find much info on it. is there any detailed explanation on using remote signer for VPS?

Answer (score 3):

It's outlined in the tezos docs here: https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/introduction/various.html#signer

One thing you need to think about is setting up a VPN or ssh tunnel or some secure connection between the signer (running on a local machine with the ledger connected) and the node in the cloud.

I can recommend taking a look at Zerotier - https://www.zerotier.com/ - for a simple and powerful approach

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation and like the convenient packaging of the Docker images.

This guy provided instructions on how to run the tezos-signer via the official Tezos Docker image: https://github.com/habanoz/tezos-signer-on-docker

I'm currently stuck at step 4, not sure how to configure my baker and accuser Docker containers to use the tezos-mainnet-signer container I got up and running.