# Unix.ECONNREFUSED with running baker on vps with remote signer

Tags: baking, remote-signer

Trying for the first time to run a mainnet baker on a vps, using a remote signer on a home laptop with Nano ledger. Node is synced. As soon as the baker tries to endorse, it throws the below error

https://tezos.gitlab.io/

```
    skipping preendorsement for baker (tz1*****************
Oct  5 04:59:02.520 - 014-PtKathma.baker.actions:   Error:
Oct  5 04:59:02.520 - 014-PtKathma.baker.actions:     Rpc request failed:
Oct  5 04:59:02.520 - 014-PtKathma.baker.actions:        - meth: GET
Oct  5 04:59:02.520 - 014-PtKathma.baker.actions:        - uri: http://aaa.bb.cc.ddd:xxxx/authorized_keys
Oct  5 04:59:02.520 - 014-PtKathma.baker.actions:        - error: Unable to connect to the node: "Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ECONNREFUSED, "connect", "")"
```

baker process is being run as `tezos-baker-014-PtKathma --remote-signer http://aaa.bb.cc.ddd:xxxx -f /home/yyyyy/pwdfile run with local node /home/yyyyy/.tezos-node baker --liquidity-baking-toggle-vote pass` and on the home laptop the signer is running as `tezos-signer --base-dir /home/zzzzz/tezos-signer-remote --require-authentication launch http signer -a aaa.bb.cc.ddd -p xxxx`  Port xxxx on the home laptop is open in the firewall rules. Home laptop running Ubuntu 20.04  I'm sure I'm missing some import steps along the way, even though I was trying to follow https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/key-management.html. Or, I'm not running the remote signer with the wrong attributes.  Any ideas where I should start looking?

EDIT:  Tried redoing the key management steps, but slightly different
On the home laptop:

```
tezos-signer --base-dir /home/yyyyy/tezos-signer-remote import secret key baker ledger://xxxxxxxx-yyyyyyy-zz-aaa/ed25519/0h/0h
nohup tezos-signer --base-dir /home/yyyyy/tezos-signer-remote --require-authentication launch http signer -a aaa.bb.cc.ddd -p xxxx &
```

On the vps:
`tezos-client import secret key baker http://aaa.bb.cc.ddd:xxxx/tz1***************************` but now getting this error

```
 Rpc request failed:
     - meth: GET
     - uri: http://aaa.bb.cc.ddd:xxxx/tz1***************************
TEZOS_MAINNET"Unable to connect to the node: "Failed to read response: Malformed response first line: <garbage characters>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through [How to run a baker with ledger (remote signer)](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/525/how-to-run-a-baker-with-ledger-remote-signer?rq=1), I ended up setting up a tunnel between the vps and the home laptop using zerotier.com. That worked, although instead of the error showing up, the connection from the baker on the vps to remote signer seemed to hang. That was resolved by removing the --require-authentication option from the tezos-signer process

Comment: If you found a good solution to your own question it's OK for you to approve it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should run a node on the VPS (with `home/yyyyy/.tezos-node` as data-dir) and open its RPC port to localhost.

Comment: Node's running on the vps, tezos-node run --data-dir /home/yyyyy/.tezos-node --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1